# Jquery show/hide. Multiple instances of a class

Tags: jquery, animation

I've managed to sort out a little slice of Jquery to show and hide a div based on someone hovering the cursor over its parent div. I want to use the same classes to have multiple instances of this on the page. Code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.focus_hidden').hide();
    $('.focus_col').hover(function() {
    $('.focus_hidden').slideToggle();
    return false;
    })
})
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML (or the relevant part) and an example of the multiple instances you refer to?

Comment: Please provide us some more details about functionality and post your HTML that we can see hierarchy of your code.

Comment: Please post your efforts on http://jsfiddle.net/ it'll make it easier for people to help resolve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The part of your code reading thus...

```
$('.focus_col').hover(function() {
  $('.focus_hidden').slideToggle();
  return false;
})
```

is applying `.slideToggle` to all `focus_hidden` elements whenever *any* `focus_col` element is hovered. If you want to apply behaviour to the particular element which has been hovered you need to use `$(this)` eg `$(this).slideToggle()`

But your question lacks clarity...

Answer (score 1):

I understand that each focus_col has a focus_hidden.
One method is to put the two element in the same parent element:

```
<div class="focus">
  <div class="focus_col">COL1</div>
  <div class="focus_hidden">HIDDEN1</div>
</div>
<div class="focus">
  <div class="focus_col">COL2</div>
  <div class="focus_hidden">HIDDEN2</div>
</div>

$('.focus_col').hover(function() {
  $(this).closest('.focus').find('.focus_hidden').slideToggle();
  return false;
})
```

see my jsfiddle for example : http://jsfiddle.net/bouillard/VPG5S/

But the right method will depend on your html organization.
An other method could use data to associate elements: http://jsfiddle.net/bouillard/kCbaT/

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you included the relevant HTML, but essentially what your problem is that you are using another general selector in your hover function, when really at that point you should be targetting the DOM relative to the item being hovered.

For example:

```
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="focus_col">
       Roll over me
    </div>
    <div class="focus_hidden">
       Hidden stuff!
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="parent">
    <div class="focus_col">
       Or roll over me too
    </div>
    <div class="focus_hidden">
       Some more hidden stuff!
    </div>
  </div>
```

Then alter the jQuery slightly so in the hover function it selects the right focus_hidden based on the current item being hovered over:

```
$('.focus').hover(function() {
    $('.focus_hidden', $(this).parent()).slideToggle();
    return false;
})
```

My knowledge of the efficiencies of different selectors isn't that great, so perhaps someone can add a comment to state if the above can be improved on. It depends how flexible you want to be in your design; for example if you know that the focus_hidden div will *always* follow the focus_col, you can jump straight to it with next().

Also, I would remove the .hide() call and just alter the CSS so that focus_hidden is hidden by default, saves a bit of client-side processing.